# How to add plugin to Ionic 2 Plunker

Tags: ionic-framework, plunker

Hi I have the following Plunker for Ionic 2.

[Ionic 2 Environment](http://plnkr.co/edit/sC9sFKk0dDRw8WYR1w3c?p=preview)

I would like to add the Angular 2 Flex Layout(link below) to this plunker so that I have access to it on the home.html. How would I go about this?

[Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Many thanks in advance.

My index looks like:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.6/bundles/ionic.system.js"></script>

    <link href="https://npmcdn.com/ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.6/bundles/ionic.ios.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- this Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
    <ion-app></ion-app>

    <script>
      System.import('app.ts')
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific plunker is actually pretty out of date for both angular and ionic. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be one since 2.0 went stable let alone the 4.0 current branch.

You may get it to work with that somehow but I don't think it would be a good testing/example tool.

Update: I went ahead and got one working with blank settings. You can see it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/y8R0MF?p=info

And Here it is with Flex-Layout running

To add plugins you have to add them to the systemJs config with the path to the umd like:

```
'@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@4.1.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
```

which is a path to the unpacked version

Hope that helps!